# Динамическое формирование значения для атрибута ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть страница

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  var questions = new Array(2);
  questions[0] = {
    name: "Сколько будет 2 + 2 = ?",
    answers: [2, 3, 4, 5]
  };
  questions[1] = {
    name: "Сколько будет 2 + 2 * 2 = ?",
    answers: [4, 6, 8]
  };
  $scope.questions = questions;
  $scope.tab = 1;
  $scope.selectTab = function(setTab) {
    $scope.tab = setTab;
  }
  $scope.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
    return $scope.tab == checkTab;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h2>
  ВОПРОС    
  </h2>
    <br>
    <div ng-show='isSelected(1)'>
      {{questions[0].name}}:
      <div class="radio-class">
        <label ng-repeat="cur in questions[0].answers">
          <input type="radio" name="radio"> {{cur}}
          <br>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show='isSelected(2)'>
      {{questions[1].name}}:
      <div class="radio-class">
        <label ng-repeat="cur in questions[1].answers">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2"> {{cur}}
          <br>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <a href='#' ng-click='selectTab(1)'>1</a>
      <a href='#' ng-click='selectTab(2)'>2</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Сейчас есть только два блока `div` c вопросами. Но в реальности их будет больше. Есть ли возможность как-то с помощью ng-repeat или другим способом избежать дублирование блока `div` с вопросом?

При формировании блока с вопросом, необходимо динамически:

- менять значение атрибута `ng-show='isSelected(n)'`;
- менять индекс коллекции `questions[n]`;
- и пронумеровать элемент input в его атрибуте `name="radioN"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `$index`:

```
<body>
  <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h2>ВОПРОС</h2>
    <br>

    <div ng-repeat="question in questions" ng-show='isSelected($index+1)'>
      {{question.name}}:
      <div class="radio-class">
        <label ng-repeat="cur in question.answers">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" value="{{$index+1}}"> {{cur}}
          <br>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>    

    <nav>
      <a ng-repeat="question in questions" ng-click="selectTab($index+1)">{{$index+1}}</a>          
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```